# "Successful" Netlify Form Submissions Don't Show in Dashboard

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, netlify

I have a create-react-app application deployed to Netlify, and I'm using [react-netlify-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-netlify-form) to render my form. My form is registered in my Netlify dashboard, and when I make a submission, I get the success response, but no submissions show up in my Netlify dashboard.

Initially I tried creating a form using the [netlify form with react](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/) guide. It registered in the Netlify dashboard, but submissions would not show up. (I made sure to use the static form in my index.html file, and the hidden input field with the form name in the react form.)

Then I tried using the **react-netlify-form** package, and I'm still having the same issue, even when a submission returns a success status.

When I look at the XHR request I see a response code of 200:
[image: xhr request for netlify form submission]

In my index.html file I have my static form for Netlify:

```
<!-- Netlify static HTML form -->
<form name="contactform" netlify netlify-honeypot="__bf" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</form>
<!-- End Netlify static HTML form -->
```

In my component I'm rendering the form like this:

```
<NetlifyForm name='contactform'>
    {({ loading, error, success }) => (
      <div>
        {loading &&
          <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        {!loading && !success &&
          <div className="jo-contact-form">
            <h2 className="jo-contact-form-title">
              Contact
            </h2>
            <div>
              <div className="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
                <label htmlFor="name">Your Name</label>
                <input className={nameClasses} type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <span className="focus-input100"></span>
              </div>
              <div className="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input className={emailClasses} type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email addess" value={email} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <span className="focus-input100"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Message is required">
              <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
              <textarea className={messageClasses} name="message" placeholder="Your message here..." value={message} onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
              <span className="focus-input100"></span>
            </div>
            <LinkButton text="Send" linkType="form" />  
          </div>
        }
        {error &&
          <div className="jo-contact-form-submission-message jo-contact-form-error">
            <div>
              Your information was not sent. Please try again later.
            </div>
          </div>
        }
        {success &&
          <div className="jo-contact-form-submission-message jo-contact-form-success">
            <div>
              Thanks for the message! Expect a reply shortly. 
            </div>
        </div>
        }
      </div>
    )}
</NetlifyForm>
```

In my HTML when the app is rendered that form ends up looking like this:

```
<form name="contactform" action="/" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="__bf">
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contactform"><input type="text" name="__bf" style="display: none;">
  <div>
      <div class="jo-contact-form">
        <h2 class="jo-contact-form-title">Contact</h2>
        <div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required"><label for="name">Your Name</label><input class="input100" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" value=""><span class="focus-input100"></span></div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz"><label for="email">Email</label><input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email addess" value=""><span class="focus-input100"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Message is required"><label for="message">Message</label><textarea class="input100" name="message" placeholder="Your message here..."></textarea><span class="focus-input100"></span></div>
        <div class="jo-link-button-wrapper">
            <div class="jo-link-button undefined form">
              <button type="submit" style="background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25); border: 1px solid rgb(25, 25, 25); color: white;">
                  <span class="button-text">Send</span>
                  <span class="button-arrow">
                    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 476.213 476.213">
                        <polygon fill="white" points="345.606,107.5 324.394,128.713 418.787,223.107 0,223.107 0,253.107 418.787,253.107 324.394,347.5  345.606,368.713 476.213,238.106 "></polygon>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
              </button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Based on the form being recognized in the Netlify dashboard, and the success message I get up on submission, I'd expect the submissions to show up in my dashboard, but there's nothing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a fix for this in case anyone else runs into a similar issue. It turns out the **'content-type'** header needs to be **'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'**. I ended up scrapping the **react-netlify-form** package and using this component which works for me.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import  './Contact.css';
import LinkButton from '../LinkButton/LinkButton';
import qs from 'qs';

class Contact extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      canSubmit: false,
      submitResponse: false
    };  
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (!this.state.canSubmit) {
      return false;
    }

    let formData = {
      "form-name": this.props.name,
      "name": this.state.name,
      "email": this.state.email,
      "message": this.state.message,
    }

    fetch( window.location.href + "/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: qs.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(
      response => {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(response.status)
        if (response.status > 199 && response.status < 300){
          this.setState(prevState=>({
            submitResponse: 'success'
          }))
        } else {
          this.setState(prevState=>({
            submitResponse: 'error'
          }))
        } 
      }
    )
    .catch(
      error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.setState(prevState=>({
          submitResponse: 'error'
        }))
      }
    );
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    if ( this.state.name !== '' && this.state.email !== '' && this.state.message !== '') {
      console.log('fields filled in');
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        canSubmit: true
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        canSubmit: false
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {

    const { name, email, message, canSubmit } = this.state;
    let containerClasses = 'jo-contact-form-container';
    if (!canSubmit) { containerClasses += ' inactive'; }
    if (this.props.colorScheme == 'dark' ) containerClasses += ' dark-bg';
    let nameClasses = 'input100';
    if (name !== '') nameClasses += ' has-val';
    let emailClasses = 'input100';
    if (email !== '') emailClasses += ' has-val';
    let messageClasses = 'input100';
    if (message !== '') messageClasses += ' has-val';


    return <div className="jo-contact-form">
      <h2 className="jo-contact-form-title">Contact</h2>
      {!this.state.submitResponse &&
        <form name={this.props.name} method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} data-netlify-recaptcha="true">
          <div className={containerClasses}>
            <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contactpageform"/>
            <div>
              <div className="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
                <label htmlFor="name">Your Name</label>
                <input className={nameClasses} type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <span className="focus-input100"></span>
              </div>
              <div className="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
                <label htmlFor="email">Your Email</label>
                <input className={emailClasses} type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <span className="focus-input100"></span>
              </div>
              <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
                <textarea className={messageClasses} name="message" onChange={this.handleChange} value={message}/>
                <span className="focus-input100"></span>
              </div>
              {canSubmit && <LinkButton size="large" text="Send" linkType="form" />}
              {!canSubmit && <LinkButton size="large" text="Send" linkType="form" inactive={true} />}
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      }
      {this.state.submitResponse == 'success' &&
        <div className="jo-contact-form-submission-message jo-contact-form-success">
          <div>Thanks for the message! Expect a reply shortly.</div>
        </div>
      }
      {this.state.submitResponse == 'error' &&
        <div className="jo-contact-form-submission-message jo-contact-form-error">
          <div>Your information was not sent. Please try again later.</div>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  }
}

export default Contact;
```