# “Successful” Static Netlify Form Submissions Don't Show in Dashboard

Tags: forms, netlify

I have a completely static html form with some data using the netlify tag. When I submit it, I get a 200 and see the default success page, but do not see the submission in the Netlify Dashboard. I do see the form was recognized and has an entry in the dashboard, but it shows zero submissions.

Note that my issue is different from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755148/successful-netlify-form-submissions-dont-show-in-dashboard) because this is a static form and my content-type is already "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which was what was wrong in that other case.

I don't see anyone else describing this issue and I can't seem to find anything in the docs that I might be missing. Anyone seen this before and found a solution?

Here's the form:

```
                <form name="registration" method="POST" class="registration-form" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-recaptcha="true">
                    <H2>Juneteenth Parade Registration Form</H2>
                    <p>The deadline to register for the parade is Fri. May 31, 2019.</p>
                    <fieldset>

                        <legend>CONTACT INFORMATION</legend>

                        <div class="registration-form">
                            <label for="name">Organization Name:</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="128" size="64">
                        </div>

                        <div class="registration-form">
                            <label for="contact">Contact Person:</label><input type="text" id="person" name="person" required minlength="4" maxlength="128" size="64">
                        </div>

                        <div class="registration-form">
                            <label for="address">Organization Address:</label><input type="text" id="address" name="address" required minlength="4" maxlength="128" size="64">
                        </div>

                        <div class="registration-form">
                            <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label><input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="###-###-####" id="phone" name="phone" required minlength="7" maxlength="28" size="14">
                        </div>

                        <div class="registration-form">
                            <label for="alt_phone">Alternate Phone:</label><input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="###-###-####" id="alt_phone" name="alt_phone" required minlength="7" maxlength="28" size="14">
                        </div>

                        <div class="registration-form">
                            <label for="email">E-mail Address:</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required minlength="4" maxlength="128" size="32">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>

                        <legend>PARADE ENTRY</legend>

                        <div class="description">
                            <label for="description">Please describe the nature of your parade entry for example; float, people walking together, band, horse and buggy, decorated car, bicycles and banners.</label>                       <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="3" cols="64">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="registration-form">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="music" name="music">
                            <label for="music">Playing or performing music?</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="number-of-people">
                            <label for="people">Number of people expected:</label><input type="number" id="email" name="email" required minlength="1" maxlength="4" size="4">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Registration" class="submit button">
                </form>
```

And here's the request/response:

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      "name": "WebInspector",
      "version": "537.36"
    },
    "pages": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2019-04-14T21:45:06.072Z",
        "id": "page_4",
        "title": "https://redacted.netlify.com/",
        "pageTimings": {
          "onContentLoad": 364.39100000006874,
          "onLoad": 418.19699999996374
        }
      }
    ],
    "entries": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2019-04-14T21:45:06.070Z",
        "time": 225.2770000000055,
        "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "https://redacted.netlify.com/",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": ":method",
              "value": "POST"
            },
            {
              "name": ":authority",
              "value": "redacted.netlify.com"
            },
            {
              "name": ":scheme",
              "value": "https"
            },
            {
              "name": ":path",
              "value": "/"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-length",
              "value": "585"
            },
            {
              "name": "pragma",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "cache-control",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "origin",
              "value": "https://redacted.netlify.com"
            },
            {
              "name": "upgrade-insecure-requests",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            {
              "name": "user-agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept",
              "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3"
            },
            {
              "name": "referer",
              "value": "https://redacted.netlify.com/"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 585,
          "postData": {
            "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "text": "form-name=registration&name=Test+Org&person=Bill&address=111+Test+Dr.&phone=111-222-3333&alt_phone=444-555-6666&email=me%40example.com&description=This+is+a+test.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++&music=on&email=1&g-recaptcha-response=03AOLTBLTRjCCETaPINwgzeeptXELZzjz9ineERJ18sHv9_Pb4ou7P70RkIz4vqEJPMME01RnXgqSjs-0f_6TUjWEL3QkkFJSd2dThUktYnI5Y-Nwl8fJx4DMU9ZBPuL1MLM-vjOiRf2ZNHU13HxrSUk3ab9j31O4R8wnTtdpG_QiQwKMxZs-pM-_L29YBA1c4HGR1IZJlxGixjk06L50CLzc6cF9y_o6RHiZ8O33hJ_36sgTWEqjeSjZUU9XHRPFkkCUK9x5LK5P5j2HFOEjpA6NbOqHyTtLGUo8CnvgwlLDiovvwASyRD0vmz0gkMTHV1LBsjoAWkSACLz1o5dh2mpdsXVZUfZo-jA",
            "params": [
              {
                "name": "form-name",
                "value": "registration"
              },
              {
                "name": "name",
                "value": "Test+Org"
              },
              {
                "name": "person",
                "value": "Bill"
              },
              {
                "name": "address",
                "value": "111+Test+Dr."
              },
              {
                "name": "phone",
                "value": "111-222-3333"
              },
              {
                "name": "alt_phone",
                "value": "444-555-6666"
              },
              {
                "name": "email",
                "value": "me%40example.com"
              },
              {
                "name": "description",
                "value": "This+is+a+test.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
              },
              {
                "name": "music",
                "value": "on"
              },
              {
                "name": "email",
                "value": "1"
              },
              {
                "name": "g-recaptcha-response",
                "value": "[redacted]"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "status",
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "text/html"
            },
            {
              "name": "date",
              "value": "Sun, 14 Apr 2019 21:45:06 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "age",
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "server",
              "value": "Netlify"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-nf-request-id",
              "value": "0cb00dd4-87f1-42a7-b737-913d0998120e-98519701"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 2121,
            "mimeType": "text/html",
            "text": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\n    <title>Thank you!</title>\n    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>\n    <style>\n    body {\n      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, \"Segoe UI\", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, \"Apple Color Emoji\", \"Segoe UI Emoji\", \"Segoe UI Symbol\";\n      background: rgb(14, 30, 37);\n      color: white;\n      overflow: hidden;\n    }\n\n    h1 {\n      margin: 0;\n      font-size: 22px;\n      line-height: 24px;\n    }\n\n    .main {\n      position: relative;\n      display: flex;\n      flex-direction: column;\n      align-items: center;\n      justify-content: center;\n      height: 100vh;\n      width: 100vw;\n    }\n\n    .card {\n      position: relative;\n      display: flex;\n      flex-direction: column;\n      width: 75%;\n      max-width: 364px;\n      padding: 24px;\n      background: white;\n      color: rgb(14, 30, 37);\n      border-radius: 8px;\n      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(14, 30, 37, .16);\n    }\n\n    a {\n      margin: 0;\n      text-decoration: none;\n      font-weight: 600;\n      line-height: 24px;\n      color: #00ad9f;\n    }\n\n    a svg {\n      position: relative;\n      top: 2px;\n    }\n\n    a:hover,\n    a:focus {\n      text-decoration: underline;\n      color: #007A70;\n    }\n\n    a:hover svg path{\n      fill: #007A70;\n    }\n\n    p:last-of-type {\n      margin: 0;\n    }\n    </style>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n\n    <div class=\"main\">\n      <div class=\"card\">\n        <div class=\"header\">\n          <h1>Thank you!</h1>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"body\">\n\n          <p>Your form submission has been received.</p>\n\n          <p>\n            <a id=\"back-link\" href=\"/\">← Back to our site</a>\n          </p>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n    <script>\n      (function() {\n        if (document.referrer && document.location.host && document.referrer.match(new RegExp(\"^https?://\" + document.location.host))) {\n          document.getElementById(\"back-link\").setAttribute(\"href\", document.referrer);\n        }\n      })();\n    </script>\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": -1,
          "_transferSize": 2210
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 2.34500000006365,
          "dns": -1,
          "ssl": -1,
          "connect": -1,
          "send": 0.16100000000000003,
          "wait": 221.8270000000515,
          "receive": 0.9439999998903659,
          "_blocked_queueing": 1.86600000006365
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "142.93.122.177",
        "_initiator": {
          "type": "other"
        },
        "_priority": "VeryHigh",
        "_resourceType": "document",
        "connection": "19503",
        "pageref": "page_4"
      },
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2019-04-14T21:45:06.311Z",
        "time": 126.6409999998271,
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0+quic/43",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://redacted.netlify.com/"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [
            {
              "name": "family",
              "value": "Roboto:400,700"
            },
            {
              "name": "subset",
              "value": "latin,latin-ext"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0+quic/43",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "strict-transport-security",
              "value": "max-age=31536000"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-encoding",
              "value": "br"
            },
            {
              "name": "last-modified",
              "value": "Sun, 14 Apr 2019 21:45:06 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "server",
              "value": "ESF"
            },
            {
              "name": "access-control-allow-origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "date",
              "value": "Sun, 14 Apr 2019 21:45:06 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-frame-options",
              "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "text/css; charset=utf-8"
            },
            {
              "name": "status",
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "name": "alt-svc",
              "value": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,44,43,39\""
            },
            {
              "name": "cache-control",
              "value": "private, max-age=86400, stale-while-revalidate=604800"
            },
            {
              "name": "timing-allow-origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "link",
              "value": "<https://fonts.gstatic.com>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-xss-protection",
              "value": "1; mode=block"
            },
            {
              "name": "expires",
              "value": "Sun, 14 Apr 2019 21:45:06 GMT"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 4498,
            "mimeType": "text/css",
            "text": "[redacted]"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": -1,
          "_transferSize": 854
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 14.100000000016415,
          "dns": 27.329,
          "ssl": 46.616,
          "connect": 74.052,
          "send": 0,
          "wait": 10.321999999880063,
          "receive": 0.8379999999306165,
          "_blocked_queueing": 13.277000000016415
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "172.217.9.170",
        "_initiator": {
          "type": "parser",
          "url": "https://redacted.netlify.com/",
          "lineNumber": 6
        },
        "_priority": "VeryHigh",
        "_resourceType": "stylesheet",
        "pageref": "page_4"
      },
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2019-04-14T21:45:06.424Z",
        "time": 48.637999999755266,
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v19/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4.woff2",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0+quic/43",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext"
            },
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "https://redacted.netlify.com"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0+quic/43",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "date",
              "value": "Mon, 25 Mar 2019 20:21:40 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-content-type-options",
              "value": "nosniff"
            },
            {
              "name": "last-modified",
              "value": "Mon, 25 Mar 2019 20:13:46 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "server",
              "value": "sffe"
            },
            {
              "name": "age",
              "value": "1733006"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "font/woff2"
            },
            {
              "name": "status",
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "name": "alt-svc",
              "value": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,44,43,39\""
            },
            {
              "name": "cache-control",
              "value": "public, max-age=31536000"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-ranges",
              "value": "bytes"
            },
            {
              "name": "timing-allow-origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "access-control-allow-origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-length",
              "value": "15816"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-xss-protection",
              "value": "1; mode=block"
            },
            {
              "name": "expires",
              "value": "Tue, 24 Mar 2020 20:21:40 GMT"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 15816,
            "mimeType": "font/woff2",
            "text": "[redacted]",
            "encoding": "base64"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": -1,
          "_transferSize": 15920
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 2.2409999998616694,
          "dns": -1,
          "ssl": -1,
          "connect": -1,
          "send": 0.08200000000000002,
          "wait": 45.09700000001289,
          "receive": 1.2179999998807034,
          "_blocked_queueing": 1.9459999998616695
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "216.58.194.67",
        "_initiator": {
          "type": "script",
          "stack": {
            "callFrames": [
              {
                "functionName": "",
                "scriptId": "368",
                "url": "chrome-extension://mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.6/js/jquery-1.4.2.js",
                "lineNumber": 20,
                "columnNumber": 266
              },
              {
                "functionName": "ready",
                "scriptId": "368",
                "url": "chrome-extension://mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.6/js/jquery-1.4.2.js",
                "lineNumber": 10,
                "columnNumber": 196
              },
              {
                "functionName": "B",
                "scriptId": "368",
                "url": "chrome-extension://mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.6/js/jquery-1.4.2.js",
                "lineNumber": 17,
                "columnNumber": 6
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "_priority": "VeryHigh",
        "_resourceType": "font",
        "pageref": "page_4"
      },
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2019-04-14T21:45:06.431Z",
        "time": 53.76699999987977,
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v19/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0+quic/43",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext"
            },
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "https://redacted.netlify.com"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0+quic/43",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "date",
              "value": "Mon, 25 Mar 2019 20:21:59 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-content-type-options",
              "value": "nosniff"
            },
            {
              "name": "last-modified",
              "value": "Mon, 25 Mar 2019 20:12:01 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "server",
              "value": "sffe"
            },
            {
              "name": "age",
              "value": "1732987"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "font/woff2"
            },
            {
              "name": "status",
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "name": "alt-svc",
              "value": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,44,43,39\""
            },
            {
              "name": "cache-control",
              "value": "public, max-age=31536000"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-ranges",
              "value": "bytes"
            },
            {
              "name": "timing-allow-origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "access-control-allow-origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-length",
              "value": "15736"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-xss-protection",
              "value": "1; mode=block"
            },
            {
              "name": "expires",
              "value": "Tue, 24 Mar 2020 20:21:59 GMT"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 15736,
            "mimeType": "font/woff2",
            "text": "[redacted]",
            "encoding": "base64"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": -1,
          "_transferSize": 15840
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 4.55399999966129,
          "dns": -1,
          "ssl": -1,
          "connect": -1,
          "send": 0.15599999999999992,
          "wait": 39.65100000009211,
          "receive": 9.406000000126369,
          "_blocked_queueing": 3.0159999996612896
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "216.58.194.67",
        "_initiator": {
          "type": "script",
          "stack": {
            "callFrames": [
              {
                "functionName": "",
                "scriptId": "368",
                "url": "chrome-extension://mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.6/js/jquery-1.4.2.js",
                "lineNumber": 20,
                "columnNumber": 266
              },
              {
                "functionName": "ready",
                "scriptId": "368",
                "url": "chrome-extension://mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.6/js/jquery-1.4.2.js",
                "lineNumber": 10,
                "columnNumber": 196
              },
              {
                "functionName": "B",
                "scriptId": "368",
                "url": "chrome-extension://mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.6/js/jquery-1.4.2.js",
                "lineNumber": 17,
                "columnNumber": 6
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "_priority": "VeryHigh",
        "_resourceType": "font",
        "pageref": "page_4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: Make sure your input name attributes are all unique. The submit will fail silently otherwise.

Posting this as an answer to help anyone else who runs into this. It turns out that some form errors, in this case an input with a duplicate name, will appear to submit successfully, but will actually either go to spam or be lost.

To confirm, I created a new form, identical to the first, but with all of the inputs named correctly. The form submitted fine and showed up in the dashboard immediately.

I then changed the last input to have a name already used by another input "email" in this case. The submission appeared to be successful, but the data never showed-up in the dashboard.

Changing the name back to a unique name and trying again submitted successfully and immediately showed up in the dashboard.

Here's what my mistake looked like.

```
<div class="registration-form">
  <label for="email">E-mail Address:</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" required minlength="4" maxlength="128">
</div>

...

<div class="registration-form">
  <input type="number" id="number" name="email" required minlength="1" maxlength="4" size="4" class="number"> <label for="people">Number of people expected?</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Bill. Good it's being figured out at the end

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with a Netlify form - showed as successful but then it wasn't actually submitted. Can you try to switch the `data-netlify="true"` to just `netlify`? That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That didn't seem to help in this case. Had an answer back from Support on the forum. They suggest it might be anti-spam filters kicking in after I used test data like me@example.com 123Test etc. I'll post back here once I know for sure.

Comment: Oh, okay. That's something hard to catch. Did it work with some proper data?

Comment: No luck so far. I also tried with a different laptop/browser and over my work VPN, so if this is spam filtering, it's possibly psychic. I'll see if I can learn more from Netlify.

Comment: Here's what I know support was able to clear the spam flags and send all of the test submissions, but new submissions still failed silently. Since I still needed to get this site up, I switched to a form to email service and discovered that I had two fields with the same name="email" attribute. I can't definitively say this is the fix since I don't have time to retest tonight, but I will test with a new page as soon as I can and report back here.

Comment: Okay, you might actually have/had a number of issues. Did the double named field cause it to break?

Comment: I was able to confirm it and confirm that fixing it fixes the form. I went ahead and created an answer in case anyone else runs into this. I'll update the forum too.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, but I resolved it using the following steps: Firstly, I uploaded the folder containing the form. Then, I accessed the site settings and navigated to the forms section, where I enabled the Form detection feature. Subsequently, I redeployed the site by uploading the same folder once again. Therefore, in order to achieve the desired outcome, you would need to enable form detection and then deploy the site. This approach worked successfully for me.