# Vue Netlify Form successful submission but doesn't show in netlify website

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs2, netlify

We have a form in Vue app set to submit data to Netlify. Everything seems to work, but there are no forms or submissions in Netlify Dashboard.

We've followed guides on netlify website regarding Vue app ([LINK1](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/07/how-to-integrate-netlify-forms-in-a-vue-app/)) as well as the solutions found on stackoverflow ([LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755148/successful-netlify-form-submissions-dont-show-in-dashboard) & [LINK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680615/successful-static-netlify-form-submissions-dont-show-in-dashboard)) that have similar issues, but none seem to work.

Here is the code:

Form

```
div(class="input")
          form(method="post" @submit.prevent="submitForm")
            input(type="hidden" name="form-name" value="ask-question")
            input(type="text" name="name" :label="name" v-model="contactInput.name")
            input(type="text" name="email" :label="email" v-model="contactInput.email")
            input(type="text" name="phone" :label="phone" v-model="contactInput.phone")
            textarea(solo name="message" :label="message" v-model="contactInput.message" no-resize)
            v-btn(type="submit" color="info") {{Submit}}
```

Functions

```
private encode(data: any) {
    return Object.keys(data)
      .map(
        key => ${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(data[key])}
      )
      .join('&');
  }
  private submitForm(){
    fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: this.encode({ 'form-name': 'ask-question', ...this.contactInput }),
      })
        .then((data) => alert("Success!")
        .catch(error => alert(error));
  }
```

We expected to see Success! message and a form and submissions in our Netlify dashboard. We tested and we saw Success! message but nothing in Netlify's dashboard according to Form section.

Comment: Looks like you have a form-name input field. Try adding the name of the form to the form element

Comment: @aprouja1 I've tried this `form(method="post" @submit.prevent="submitForm" name="ask-question")` but it did not work

Comment: Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: No I didn't @Rasul Kireev